# Email Routing in organization

Tags: email, smtp, smtpclient, email-client

> i want to develop a system by which i cud route my incoming emails .
>   my system scenario comprises with departments, employees, HOD(head of
>   dept.).lets if A is in dept D and A is HOD of D and under A there are
>   4 employees(W,X,Y,Z).
>
> If A receives the email then the copy of email should be forwarded to
>   its under employees(W,X,Y,Z). how could we do this using smtp servers.
>
> please suggest me how can i do that ?
>
> thank you

Comment: This is not a programming question (nominating for migration to http://serverfault.com/) and also not SMTP per se, as that is the protocol for transporting mail between domains, not for local delivery. More details about your platform (Unix, Windows; if the latter, Exchange hell or the regular inferno?) would be required for any substantial answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mail servers have a way to forward a copy of an message to another user's address  (in additional to routing the message to the original recipient's mailbox).  If the mail server is running on a Linux system, this is usually done using a .forward file.  See http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/qmail/users/42753 for more info.